# Writing a for loop for nine buttons

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm creating a simple naughts and crosses game in Android Studio for a university project, but I'm struggling to create a for loop for each of the nine buttons that loop through the arrays. How do would I go about this doing this?

Here is the code for the nine buttons to set the event listeners in the OnClickListener.

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
        buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        buttons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single click listener for all buttons and then use a switch statement on the view id to determine which button was clicked. And you should start your array at 0, not 1.

```
private final View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.one:
                // do stuff;
                break;
            case R.id.two:
                // do stuff;
                break;
            case R.id.three:
                // do stuff;
                break;
            case R.id.four:
                // do stuff;
                break;
            // add more
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply set this listener to your buttons

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(mListener);
}
```

Comment: what about one hundred button still switch case,

Comment: If you have 100 buttons in your UI, you're probably doing it wrong. But the same principle applies. Alternatively, you could define the buttons programmatically and assign them a tag that you would use instead of the ID.

Comment: most of time I have som issue like this in android I would recommend somthing like     **  for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    { 
        buttons[i] =(Button)findViewWithTag("tag"+String.valueOf(i));
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(mListener);


    }**